# delete the rows with duplicated ids

Tags: r, delete-row, duplicate-data

I want to delete the rows with duplicated ids

data

```
id    V1    V2   
1     a      1
1     b      2
2     a      2
2     c      3
3     a      4
```

The problem is that some people did the test for a few times, which generate multiple scores on V2, I want to delete the duplicated id and retain one of the scores in V2 randomly.

output

```
id    V1    V2   
1     a      1
2     a      2
3     a      4
```

I tried this:

```
neu <- unique(neu$userid)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: `df[!duplicated(df$id),]`?

Comment: tried this already, Error in df[!duplicated(neu$userid), ] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Try `df[!duplicated(df$userid), ]`

Comment: Error in df[!duplicated(df$userid), ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Then post a more relevant example. The code works perfectly well with the MWE you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df %>% sample_frac(., 1) %>% arrange(id) %>% distinct(id)
```

Output:

```
  id V1 V2
1  1  b  2
2  2  c  3
3  3  a  4
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), V1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("id", "V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the data frame based on your example:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"id    V1    V2   
1     a      1
1     b      2
2     a      2
2     c      3
3     a      4", h = T)
```

Since you want to remove rows randomly, first sort the rows of your data frame randomly:

```
df <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

Then remove duplicates in the order of appearence:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df$id),]
```

Now sort your data frame back:

```
df <- df[with(df, order(id)),]
```

Remember to change `df` by your data frame name.